# Portable Mac Web Development IDE?

Tags: ide, portability

My graphic design teacher, is going to let me use the school's imacs during breaks to do web development work. The only problem is that the imacs have software on it that delete any files written to hard drive when you log off, so I am in need of a portable app. An eclipse app like aptana is preferable. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't go wrong with vim.

Comment: Can you keep your files on a thumb drive?